# Earning the event argument from a non-callback function (normal function calling)

Tags: javascript

I want to get the **event** argument from a normal function calling.
in callback functions we do something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('something', function(e){e.target.parentNode...etc});
```

**Here is my code**

```
<div class="options">
    <div onclick="controller.question_type('circleTheCorrectAnswer')">Circle The Correct Answer</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 const controller = (()=>{

  const question_type = (x)=>{
    console.log(x.target.parentNode);
    console.log(x.target);
  }

  return {
    question_type: question_type
  }

 })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
<div onclick="controller.question_type('circleTheCorrectAnswer')">
```

is a rough equivalent of

```
document.addEventListener('click', controller.question_type('circleTheCorrectAnswer'));
```

The problem with the above is that you're not returning a function from controller.question_type(), hence the event has nowhere to be passed.

You can change the question_type to something like

```
const question_type = (type) => {
  console.log(`type is ${type}`)
  return (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.parentNode);
    console.log(event.target);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'using' it.